# Align two bootstrap tables by column?

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am currently using bootstrap and laravel form control to create theses table structures below. The only issue I am running into now is that I cannot figure out how to get the delete and edit buttons from two separate tables to line up? Attached is a photo of what it looks like now as well as the code for displaying the tables.

[image]

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <a href="/incidents/create" class="btn btn-primary">Create Incident</a>
                        <a href="/servers/create" class="btn btn-primary">Create Server</a>
                        <h1></h1>
                        <h3>Your Incidents </h3>
                        @if($incidents)
                            <table class='table table-striped'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach($incidents as $incident)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>{{$incident->title}} : <strong>{{$incident->status}}</strong></h4></td>
                                    <td><a href="/incidents/edit/{{$incident->id}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['IncidentsController@destroy', $incident->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!}
                                        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                                        {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
                                        {!!Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </table>
                        @endif

                        <h3>Your Servers </h3>
                        @if($servers)
                            <table class='table table-striped'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Server Names</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach($servers as $server)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>{{$server->name}}</h4></td>
                                    <td><a href="/servers/edit/{{$server->id}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['ServerController@destroy', $server->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!}
                                        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                                        {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
                                        {!!Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </table>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Thank you in advance and any help on how I could line up the columns for the two different tables would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the tables as rendered HTML?

Comment: Tables don't relate to each other. You will have to specify the width of both table columns if you want them to match. Personally, I would not even bother to use tables because using plain div's styles way easier using CSS grids.

Comment: do you want it like this? https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/YvegLj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use Bootstrap 4 [sizing utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/) to set defined widths on the table heading columns...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
       <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="w-50">Server Names</th>
                    <th class="w-25"></th>
                    <th class="w-25"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>..</tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/hKnKbWhhHh

However, there's still no guarantee that the td column widths won't change depending on the their content. That's just the result of using separate tables.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I knew I was just over looking something, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Give the edit and delete `<td>`'s a css class forcing a maximum width. Then it won't auto spread out like that.

```
<td class="smallbox">
```

And in CSS you can just say:

```
.smallbox {
    max-width: 40px; //or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You could always add a float css property to both your edit and delete buttons.

use float: right on the edit button, and float right on the delete button.

2) Another, simpler option, put the two buttons together in a ?